# Can't do Azure SQL Database Restore to Point in Time Using Portal

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, restore, azureportal

I am trying to restore an Azure SQL Database to a point in time.  I select Restore on the SQL Instance and the time I require (back one hour), but when I click on "Pricing Tier" the right panel does not give me any options and sits with "Configure Performance" and three "wait dots" in the middle of the panel.  I have tried in Firefox, Chrome  and Edge, all are the same.

I really need to be able to restore this DB to a point in time to examine an issue and also feel very concerned that I apparently can't restore a database should I need to. I have been able to do this in the past, so I don't understand what has changed.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: try another browser\another pc\incognito mode

Comment: As per my initial post, I tried FF, Chrome and Edge. FF and Chrome were on a Mac and Edge obviously was Windows

Comment: @Nick did you ever figure this out? I just opened a customer support issue with Microsoft, as I have a similar issue. For me, the issue is that there appears to be only 1 hour saved, and I need to go back further.